# Is it posible to use two gitrepository in same publick key?

Tags: ubuntu, github

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and I have two project folder in my system. But I need to upload both folders in to my githup account. I tried can not include my public key for both project. Can any one help me?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: This works fine as long as you're not talking about deploy keys. Can you explain how it didn't work? Did you get an error message? If so, what did it say? Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577)